# Bash script runs manually in terminal but is not executed from crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path, cron

I have a bash script that I want to be executed every 15 minutes, so I added this line to my crontab:

```
7,22,37,52 * * * * /path/to/my/script.sh
```

I've checked the directory path to be correct and the script runs correctly if I just run `/path/to/my/script.sh` manually from any directory. I have this bang line in my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

My script also references other scripts in the same directory as it, and I have run `chmod +x` on all scripts that are needed. I set the `MAILTO` to my email address and I was getting some Cron Daemon emails when I changed the line in my crontab to:

```
7,22,37,52 * * * * sh /path/to/my/script.sh
```

But I never received emails upon using

```
 7,22,37,52 * * * * /path/to/my/script.sh
```

or

```
7,22,37,52 * * * * bash /path/to/my/script.sh
```

I made sure cron is running and I've also tried redirecting the output of my script to a log file, which is also only written in when I include the sh. However, if I run `sh /path/to/my/script.sh` from the home directory, it does not work. The only ways my script actually runs is if (from any directory) I call `/path/to/my/script.sh` or `bash /path/to/my/script.sh`. I'm pretty new to writing bash scripts so any help is very welcome.

Comment: Questions about using `cron` are more appropriate for superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ah yes. I forgot that  ... But configuring cron is a common issue for many.

Comment: Be sure to read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@pvas The cron user environment should be treated with extra special care. The assumption that most users have is that they will have access to paths, directories, permissions etc. This is far from the case. Cron runs in a minimal environment and you must set up EVERYTHING - Paths, Permissions and the location where the scripts are running from.

1) I set up the environment myself.

2) I use fully expanded paths in my crontabs.

3) I make sure any directories that need to be read have read permissions.

4) I make sure that my password does not expire because that will block cron when it does.

5) Make sure underlying scripts are explicitly invoked (by Perl, Bash, Python whatever).

6) Pipe the command on the cron line to a LOG file (even better a log file with a TIMESTAMP).

Fix these things and then try again. Cron is particular, you need to set up everything.

For example:

```
#SETUP ENVIRONMENT
SHELL=/bin/bash
source /home/userfoo/.bash_profile

#RUN THE SCRIPT everyday at 11:50pm (23:50)
50   23  *    *   *  userfoo /home/userfoo/script.sh >> LOGFILE.txt
```

<<

Comment: I verified that everything in your list was correct on my end and changed my line to: 7,22,37,52 * * * * my_username /path/to/my/script.sh, including my username as in your example, and now the Cron Daemon emailer is saying: /bin/sh: 1: my_username: not found, even though if I run echo $USER, I get my_username. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work now? Also make sure that there are NO relative paths in script.sh and it cd's to the directory it was invoked from or wherever it is supposed to operate - That can be another issue.

Also PIPE everything to a log

7,22,37,52 * * * * bash /path/to/my/script.sh >> LOG.txt

Comment: All of my variables have declarations with absolute paths- the only ones that are relative are when I create files after cd'ing to the required directory. I also declare PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/my_bin and export PATH in one of the scripts that my main script references. Additionally, my main script.sh references some perl scripts- could this be the issue? In all of the perl scripts I include:  #!/usr/bin/env perl. Also, my LOG.txt file is empty, although it is created. When I run the script manually using either bash /path/to/my/script.sh or /path/to/my/script.sh, I get no output in command line

Comment: I changed the line to include sh /path/to/my/script.sh and got output in my LOG.txt file. The output stopped short, so I think I know which scripts may have the error. I'll keep trying to debug.

Comment: Yes keep doing that. You will find it. Also make sure your scripts echo some stuff, it will help.

Answer (score 2):

Crontab entries should have the following format

```
m h  dom mon dow   command
```

which confirms that your entry below

```
7,22,37,52 * * * * /path/to/my/script.sh
```

is correct. Having said that, you must close the crontab editor(`:wq`) for the changes to come to effect.

It is suggested you go through [[ this ]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work) cross site post which portrays the possible issues with cron jobs.

---

<sup>More about hashbang [[ here ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).</sup>

Comment: I've been saving and closing my crontab editor correctly I think, after I exit I get a message saying: crontab: installing new crontab.

Comment: @pvas : Did you follow the tips mentioned in my link and other answer? I would also recommend restarting cron daemon